# Remove Permalink From Admin Edit Post

Tags: admin, hooks, title, post-editor

Is there any way how to edit the title field in post.php?

**this field**: 
[image]

I want to remove the **permalink part** but I wasn't able to find any hook or filter for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running the most up to date version of WordPress which has made changes to how permalinks are displayed and handled. There's no longer a **View Post** button. I was able to remove the whole area using the [`get_sample_permalink_html` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_sample_permalink_html/). Just return an empty string:

```
function hide_permalink() {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink_html', 'hide_permalink' );
```