# Stop displaying Permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

How to stop displaying permalink when adding custom post Title ?

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to stop displaying the permalink on the edit page or completely remove the pages per post from existing?

Comment: Thanks @DeltaG. I would like to stop displaying the permalink on the edit page . Thanks.

Comment: Try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211300/remove-permalink-from-admin-edit-post

Comment: Thanks @vancoder. Your solution is working. Thanks.